# Constructor and Destructor in C

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I was reading a book OOC by `A.T. Schreiner`, and I'm stuck at the following line in this code:

```
struct Class {
    size_t size;
    void *(* ctor) (void *self, va_list *app);
};

struct String {
    const void *class;  // must be first
    char *text;
};


void *new(const void *_class, ...) {
    const struct Class *class = _class;     // assign the address of `struct String` class
    void *p = calloc(1, class->size);       // allocate the sizeof(struct String);

    assert(p);
    *(const struct Class **)p = class;      // Force the conversion of p and set the argument `class` as the value of this pointer.
    if(class->ctor) {
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, _class);
        p = class->ctor(p, &ap);        // Now what is `p` here, a `struct String` or `struct Class`.
                                        // and if it is `struct Class` then how it convert to `struct String` in `String_ctor` function 
                                        // given below.
        va_end(ap);
    }
    return p;
}


static void *String_ctor(void *_self, va_list *app) {
    struct String *self = _self;        
    const char *text = va_arg(*app, const char *);

    self->text = malloc(strlen(text) + 1);
    assert(self->text);
    strcpy(self->text, text);
    return self;
}


// Initialization
static const struct Class _String  = {
    sizeof(struct String),
    String_ctor
};

const void *String = &_String;



// Call like this:
int main(void) {
 void *a = new(String, "some text");
}
```

Now, as you can see, in the `new` function, the following line `p = class->ctor(p, &ap)` confused me a lot. You can see the comment described above.

Also, I want to know how `const void *class` of `struct String` is initialized by `new` function as the book said.

Comment: Actually you're right, but i already invest my 2 days into this. So it's important for me to know.

Comment: This is ramming a square peg into a round hole with one's forehead. Just say no.

Comment: I've a problem to just wanted to know how things work and I think it's good for me atleast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `p` is being assigned to the return value of `class->ctor` which is declared as `void *` so it's a void pointer. Looking at the definition of `String_ctor` you can see this returns `self` which is a `String *`, so in this case you're getting a `void *` which can safely be cast to a `String *`
2. This is achieved with `*(const struct Class **)p = class;`. Since `class` is the first member of `String`, a pointer to a `String` will have the same address as a pointer to its `class` field. So when you convert `p` to a `Class **` and write to it, you're writing to its `class` field.

Comment: Your 2nd point, `class` is the first member of `String` is ok, but in `new` function `class` is a variable declared with `const struct Class`. So, if you're saying **when you convert p to a `Class **` and write to it, you're writing to its `class` field.`** is completely wrong.

Comment: I can't see how I'm wrong. `p` points to a block of memory `sizeof(String)` bytes long, and it's safe to assume it will be used as if it pointed to a `String` (indeed, the ctor does just that). So OP is casting a `String *` to a `Class **` and writing his class pointer to it.

Comment: You're right, but your answer needs a little bit explanation and also your answer gave me some hints to understand this difficult question. You can say that `class` in `new` is a variable by `struct Class`, but `p` is allocated memory of `struct String` and after that in `*(const struct Class**)p = class` we assign the address of `struct Class` created by `String`. That's how `class` of `struct String` is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

`p` is neither `struct String` nor `struct Class`. It's a pointer. It points to a block of memory. How that memory is interpreted is an interesting question.

Assuming we pass the address of a `struct Class` object that implements a string, the first `calloc` call allocates a chunk of memory the size of `struct String`. So it's entirely reasonable to assume `p` is a pointer to `struct String`.

The `new` function knows little about `struct String` or any other "class". Almost nothing really, except the fact that the first element of any such `struct` is a pointer to a `struct Class` object. Since a pointer to any `struct` is the same as the pointer to its first element (modulo type), this makes `p` also a *pointer to a pointer* to `struct Class`. So this line:

```
*(const struct Class **)p = class;
```

assigns the proper value to that pointer-to-struct-Class which `p` is pointing to.

Now this line

```
p = class->ctor(p, &ap);
```

calls the constructor, passing the "self" pointer to it as in any OO environment. It also assigns the result of the constructor to `p` again, presumably because the ctor can (but doesn't have to) reallocate the object.

To recap: `p` is a pointer to `struct String` that `new` interprets as a pointer to the first element of `struct String`, which must be the pointer to `struct Class`.